# Целесообразность использования enum вместо varchar в больших таблицах

Tags: mysql, sql, enum, биоинформатика

Для обозначения принадлежности той или иной хромосоме в таблицах используем либо smallint, если можно просто ссылаться на номер, либо varchar(n), если приходится иметь дело с устоявшимися буквенными обозначениями, например, для человека приходится использовать varchar(2), поскольку, кроме хромосом 1-22, есть ещё половые (X, Y) и митохондриальная (MT).
Утверждается, что в этом случае использование enum вместо varchar будет эффективнее, то есть положительно скажется на уменьшении времени выборок.
Так ли это? И как правильнее будет перейти от varchar(2) к enum без деструктивных последствий? И будут ли старые запросы в уже скомпилированных программах работать по-прежнему?

Comment: *Утверждается, что в этом случае использование enum вместо varchar будет эффективнее* Да, несомненно. А, поскольку количество значений невелико, нет состоящих только из цифр, нет работы со значениями как строками - ты к тому же плавно проезжаешь мимо основных граблей от использования ENUM. *будут ли старые запросы в уже скомпилированных программах работать по-прежнему?* У тебя по этому полю сортировки нет? тогда не видать оснований к проблемам...

Comment: Сэкономите 2 байта на запись. enum с небольшим кол-вом значений будет храниться как 1 байт. ваш varchar(2) обычно занимает 2-3 байта (байты значения + 1 байт длины).

Comment: @Mike В геномах некоторых бактерий мы сэкономим гораздо больше :) Меня больше интересует время, нежели место.

Comment: @Akina А если будет использоваться уникальный ключ chr_left_right, т.е. номер хромосомы, левая позиция, правая позиции, enum не будет вредить?

Comment: С временем поэкспериментируйте. но место и время взаимосвязаны, если файл значительно больше на диске, то его просто дольше читать :). Но я сомневаюсь, что есть большая разница по времени между работой с 1 и 3 байтами. Хотя атомарно сравнить 1 байт enum конечно на несколько тактов процессора быстрее, чем взять длину varchar и сравнить полученное кол-во байт

Comment: Без информации о структуре БД и без текстов запросов это все гадание на кофейной гуще, ИМХО.